# Manipulating styles in a php for loop

Tags: php

I am trying to add some styles to some divs in a php for loop. For each alternative iteration the position style is set either `'left: 0%' or 'left:53.8462%'`, which seems to be working. But I can't figure out how to set the top style. For each consecutive `two iterations` the value of the top style is increased by `342px` while the initial value is set to 0px. In other words, for the first and second loop, top style value is 0px, but in the second and third iteration their values are incremented by 342px and so forth. The desired html output is shown below.

In the following code this part `echo ($counter % 6 == 1 ? 'top: 0px;' : 'top: 342px;');` needs to changed.

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++): ?>
<div class="card" style="position: absolute; 
    <?php echo ($i%2 ? 'left: 53.8462%;' : 'left: 0%;'); echo ($counter % 6 == 1 ? 'top: 0px;' : 'top: 342px;');?>">

    // content //

    <?php $counter++; ?>
    <?php endfor;
?>
```

Here is the desired html output:

```
<div class="card" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">

</div>

<div class="card" style="position: absolute; left: 53.8462%; top: 0px;">

</div>

<div class="card" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 342px;">

</div>

<div class="card" style="position: absolute; left: 53.8462%; top: 342px;">

</div>

<div class="card" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 684px;">

</div>

<div class="card" style="position: absolute; left: 53.8462%; top: 684px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Is it supposed to wrap back to 0 after 6 iterations?

Comment: Using modulus is generally easier if you start your count at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @Barmar, nope it should continue with the top pixel height but the initial top is 0

Comment: Then what was the point of `$counter % 6 == 1`?

Comment: The `for()` loop only prints 4 rows. How can you get 6 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you started `$counter` at `0`. Then the top is just half of the counter multiplied by `384`.

And in this case, `$counter` is the same as `$i`, so there's no need for two variables.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++): ?>
<div class="card" style="position: absolute; 
    <?php echo ($i%2 ? 'left: 53.8462%;' : 'left: 0%;'); echo 'top: ' . floor($i/2)*384 . 'px;';?>">

    // content //

    <?php endfor;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, Glad you took the time to read and solve my problem. Happy to have you!

Answer (score 0):

Set $top as:

```
 $top = floor (($i -1) / 2) * 342;
```